# Como exatamente funciona o grid area?

Tags: css, css3, grid

Estou tentando estilizar a pagina utilizando grid no CSS mas acho que ainda não compreendi muito bem como funciona o template area.

O que esto fazendo:

```css
.pai {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "img img img btn" 
    "btn img img"
}

.pai div {
  border: 1px solid;;
}

.filho1 { grid-area: img }
.filho2 { grid-area: img }
.filho3 { grid-area: img }
.filho4 { grid-area: btn }
.filho5 { grid-area: btn }
.filho6 { grid-area: img }
.filho7 { grid-area: img }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filho1">1</div>
  <div class="filho2">2</div>
  <div class="filho3">3</div>
  <div class="filho4">4</div>
  <div class="filho5">5</div>
  <div class="filho6">6</div>
  <div class="filho7">7</div>
</div>
```

Eu acho que não entendi direito esse conceito ainda,
no caso o que estou querendo fazer é duas linhas com a primeira linha de cima tendo 4 colunas, sendo que as 3 primeiras colunas serão imagens, a quarta é um botão.

Na coluna 2, quero iniciar a mesma, sendo que a primeira coluna quero que comece com o btn e as 2 ultimas colunas termine com as imagens.

É possível? Realmente queria entender melhor, esse meu exemplo sei que está com erro mas é porque não entendo na prática como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tem vários detalhes no seu `Grid`, primeiro que se vc colocar mais de um elemento com o mesmo nome de `grid-area` logicamente eles vão ficar sobrepostos, um sobre o outro. Depois que mesmo que vc queira que uma área ocupe duas colunas vc precisa "preencher" essa coluna repetindo o nome da área ou colocando um `.` tipo como abaixo

Assim:

```
grid-template-areas: 
"img1 img2 img3 btn1" 
"btn2 btn2 img4 img5"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou assim, não repetindo o `btn2` , mas colocando um `.` no início:

```
grid-template-areas: 
"img1 img2 img3 btn1" 
". btn2 img4 img5"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor olha ai como ficaria o grid que vc quer

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pai {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    grid-template-areas: 
    "img1 img2 img3 btn1" 
    "btn2 btn2 img4 img5"
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.filho1 { grid-area: img1 }
.filho2 { grid-area: img2 }
.filho3 { grid-area: img3 }
.btn1 { grid-area: btn1 }
.btn2 { grid-area: btn2 }
.filho4 { grid-area: img4 }
.filho5 { grid-area: img5 }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho1">img1</div>
    <div class="filho2">img2</div>
    <div class="filho3">img3</div>
    <div class="btn1">button1</div>
    <div class="btn2">button2</div>
    <div class="filho4">img4</div>
    <div class="filho5">img5</div>
</div>
```

Se te interessar em ver mais detalhes, aqui tem uma documentação bem interessante! https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

**Nesse guia vc vai ver que isso:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resulta nisso:**
[image: **texto em negrito**]

Comment: AGORA faz sentido kkkk. Caraca, valeu mesmo Hugão!

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho sem problemas meu caro! Eu tb fritei com Grid no início, mas depois vc vai perceber que é fácil de mais, não tem muito mistério, a não ser quando rola uns `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px , 1fr))` ai fica cabulos haha :D